# How to resolved indentationError: unexpected indent?

Tags: python, indentation

How do I rectify this error "unexpected indent" in python?

```
from fast_rcnn.config import cfg
from nms.cpu_nms import cpu_nms

def nms(dets, thresh, force_cpu=False):
    """Dispatch to either CPU or GPU NMS implementations."""

    if (dets.shape[0]) == 0:
     return []

    return cpu_nms(dets, thresh)
```

Comment: Your indentation under your `if` statement is incorrect. Your first `return` should be indented by either a tab, or four spaces depending on your convention.

Comment: give me an example please

Comment: Please see my answer :) Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for accepting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is not a copy and paste error when copying into SE, you need to change the indentation for your first return:

```
from fast_rcnn.config import cfg
from nms.cpu_nms import cpu_nms

def nms(dets, thresh, force_cpu=False):
    """Dispatch to either CPU or GPU NMS implementations."""

    if (dets.shape[0]) == 0:
        # Note the changed indentation here
        return []

    return cpu_nms(dets, thresh)
```